# Corda explict upgrades(Java)

Tags: java, corda

i want to run **ContractUpgradeFlow.Initiate** flow in **java project**. just like this:

```
 CordaRPCOps proxy = client.start(rpcUsername, rpcPassword).getProxy();
 proxy.startFlowDynamic(ContractUpgradeFlow.Initiate.class,stateAndRef,newContractClass.class);
```

but has error :

```
Required type:Class<? extends FlowLogic<? extends T>>
Provided     :Class<Initiate>
reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Initiate conforms to FlowLogic<? extends T>
```

the kotlin version is this:
https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/explicit-cordapp-upgrades/src/main/kotlin/com/upgrade/client/ClientWithLegacyConstraint.kt
How can i run ContractUpgradeFlow.Initiate in java project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason `ContractUpgradeFlow.Initiate` is not identified as `FlowLogic` type. probably because it is not a direct sub-type of `FlowLogic`. Thanks for pointing this out, I would raise a bug for this.

However, you could use a workaround to get around this, create a new flow and call the `ContractUpgradeFlow.Initiate` as a sub-flow.

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
public class ExplicitUpgradeFlow extends FlowLogic<Void> {

    private final StateAndRef oldStateAndRef;
    private final Class newContractClass;

    public ExplicitUpgradeFlow(StateAndRef oldStateAndRef, Class newContractClass) {
        this.oldStateAndRef = oldStateAndRef;
        this.newContractClass = newContractClass;
    }

    @Override
    public Void call() throws FlowException {

        subFlow(new ContractUpgradeFlow.Initiate(oldStateAndRef, newContractClass));
        return null;
    }
}
```